# How to make use of Android App Bundle in Ionic Applications?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-app-bundle

Hi i am Working with android applications , When i try to upload developer console says the message , "[image]"

I hope we can reduce the app size through it , I tried in different ways i cannot get idea for that. Please help me out. Is there any Posibilities to do that.

Comment: please try to generate sign apk using android studio

Comment: I Don't have any idea to build ionic app in to Android Studio. Can you please refer something.

Comment: if you have android studio then just open android folder from your ionic app

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Edit: See [Matti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59615902/4654246) below if you're on Cordova >= 8.1.0

---

You need to have `"cordova-android": 8.0.0` or later.

- run `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` as usual
- change into the `/platforms/android` folder and run `./gradlew bundleRelease`. On Windows, the file might be called `gradlew.bat` instead.

This outputs the bundle at `/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab`. Sign this bundle just like you would sign the APK and upload it to the Play Store.

Comment: thanks for the answer let me try , I will get back to you soon

Comment: quick note for future Googlers, if you got here from a search for why you're no longer getting `apk` files from your build: first `cordova-android@8.1.0` enabled building _both_ `apk` and `aab` files by default, and then `cordova-android@10.0.0` changed to building _only_ `aab` files by default. https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md

Answer (score 47):

Is supported natively in cordova-android >= 8.1.0

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --packageType=bundle
```

Note the extra `-- --` dashes before `--packageType`. First `--` is required by cordova. Second one is required because there is another cli tool between (ionic).

If you use cordova without ionic:

```
cordova build android --prod --release -- --packageType=bundle
```

Comment: thank you bro. its work. Please version: cordova android >= 8.1.0

Comment: except when you sign, you cannot sign using `apksigner`. you need to use `jarsigner`. e.g. `jarsigner -keystore my-release-key.keystore app-release-signed.aab app-release-key`

Comment: After I generated this .aab , and trying to upload the play store got "To upload an Android App Bundle you must be enrolled in Play App Signing." this error. Any idea on this

Comment: I'm also getting the issue on upload .aab file, To upload an Android App Bundle you must be enrolled in Play App Signing. Is there any more step need to do after created .aab file? Please help any one on this we are urgent on upload in  play store.

Comment: For sign AAB file this will be 2nd command : `jarsigner -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore releaseApp.jks ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab release`

Answer (score 2):

### Quick Answer

### Step : 1

---

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --packageType=bundle
```

### Step : 2

---

```
jarsigner -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore releaseApp.jks ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab release
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release --alias=cos-android --password=abcd  --versionCode=00001 --versionName=00001 -- -- -- --packageType=bundle

cordova build android --prod --release --alias=cos-android --password=abcd  --versionCode=00001 --versionName=00001 -- -- --packageType=bundle`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Matti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59615902/4654246) here:
I needed to use another extra -- before "--packageType" to make it work. I was using powershell and ionic. The final working command was like this :

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- -- --packageType=bundle
```

So if the command provided by Matti is generating a release .apk for you instead of an .aab, try this one instead

Answer (score 0):

Default release bundle type is **.aab** (when use --packageType=bundle). Need apk then use below commend :-

```
 ionic cordova build android --release -- -- --packageType=apk
```